# How to log in on New Relic's iPhone-app with an AppHarbor-account

Tags: appharbor, newrelic

I haven't registered directly on [New Relic's website](http://newrelic.com/), but I'm using it through AppHarbor.

How do I log in on the iPhone-app and still **get my stats from my AppHarbor-app**?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: our iOS app does not support AppHarbor accounts currently.

For accounts where you don't have a password: Just enter your email address in the first field of the iPhone app and you'll get a confirmation email instead of being asked for a password. If it goes on to asking you for a password, please open a ticket with us at https://support.newrelic.com/home and I'll get your account sorted out.

Comment: Nopes, not even close... Got an email from New Relic starting off like this: "Unfortunately, these types of accounts do not contain email addresses the normal way New Relic accounts are setup. This is due to our integration API with AppHarbor.". The answer also states that New Relic is working on a solution for this.

Comment: You're totally right Seb, we are having trouble getting AppHarbor accounts logged in to our iOS app. We'll reply to your ticket (and update here) when we get better support.